# Electromagnetic sector in a spontaneously broken theory

Tags: gauge-theory, higgs, symmetry-breaking, yang-mills

Consider a Higgs-Yang-Mills system, where the Yang-Mills field is a connection 1-form on the $G$-principal bundle $P\to M$ and the Higgs field is a section of the associated vector bundle $E=P{{\times }_{\rho }}V$, where $\rho :G\to \operatorname{Aut}\left( V \right)$ is an arbitrary representation. Suppose we are in a region of space where the Higgs field is covariantly constant and valued in the vacuum manifold ${G}/{H}\;$, where $H$ is the unbroken subgroup. In this region only the unbroken gauge fields can be excited, because $0=\left[ {{\nabla }_{\mu }},{{\nabla }_{\nu }} \right]\varphi ={{\rho }_{*}}\left( {{F}_{\mu \nu }} \right)\varphi \Rightarrow {{F}_{\mu \nu }}\in \mathfrak{h}$. These fields are all massless after spontaneous symmetry breaking.

My question is: *which direction in $\mathfrak{h}$ defines the electromagnetic field?*

In the special case where the Higgs field is in the adjoint representation, we can define the electromagnetic direction by projecting the gauge field along the Higgs field. But in a general representation I cannot think of an obvious way to associate such a direction to the Higgs field.

My attempt was to consider a linear isometry $H:V\to\mathfrak{g}$ that intertwines $Ad$ and $\rho$. Then $H\left(\varphi\right)$ will be covanriantly constant when $\varphi$ is. Is this approach valid? If yes, which other conditions should I impose on $H$, so that $H\left(\varphi\right)$ is the electromagnetic direction?

Comment: What is your definition of "electromagnetic field" here?

Comment: A U(1) subaglebra (generated by the EM direction) of the unbroken subalgebra. Is there a way to define such a direction uniquely, so that the projection of the gauge fields along this direction can be identified with the EM field? An alternative title would be "what is the definition of the electromagnetic field" in the above setup.

Comment: weak SU(2), Higgs field in fundamental (like the fermions)...
SU(2)->1. Nothing remains massles. This answer your question?
SU(2)xU(1)->U(1) because there is a linear combination.

Comment: This is a special realization of a YMH system; my question was about the general case, where after SSB there are (in general) plenty of massless gauge fields, and one of them shall be identified with the electromagnetic. In the case where $G={SU(2)}\times{U(1)}$ breaks down to $U(1)$, there is no issue; we have only one massless mode which is identified with the EM sector. About your original example, nothing remains massless because you considered the conventional potential of the Higgs field (Mexican hat). I am interested in the general case, for arbitrary potential function.

Comment: The group representation associated to the Higgs does a lot here. If you have an adjoint Higgs of SU(2) it will broke to U(1). I will denote with [i] the fundamental representation, {i,j} the representation symmetric on i and j, [i,j] the antisymmetric one. 
SU(n) with one [i] breaks to SU(n-1), because you can choose a basis in wich [i] VEV is one of your elements of your basis, and it's charged under every element of blablabla (I mean, I think it's understandable what you will get when you see the lagrangian).
SU(4) with adjoint higgs will break to SU(3)xU(1) (diag[1,1,1,-3])

Comment: When you have one higgs in a specific representation, you look at the charges it will have in a VEV compatible with the representation (search for the nicer one), they'll tell you what will be the gauge bosons...